# UPDATE table column with Difference from two columns from two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables products, orders and sales

In each of these there is a product_id which uniquely identifies a product

When they get quantity from suppliers, they are stored in orders table and when selling they are stored in sales table...

To get total orders, sales and quantity remaining

```
SELECT sum(quantity) 
  from orders as s  
 where tbl_products.product_id = s.product_id 
     ) as total_orders

SELECT sum(quantity) 
  from sales as f 
 where tbl_products.product_id = f.product_id 
     ) as total_sold

    (SELECT sum(quantity) 
       from orders as s 
      where tbl_products.product_id = s.product_id) 
  - (SELECT sum(quantity) 
       from sales as f 
      where tbl_products.product_id = f.product_id) as qty_remaining
```

Now I want to update the third table which is the products table and has the quantity column.

I have tried the following

```
UPDATE products 
   SET quantity = 
       (SELECT sum(quantity) 
          from orders as s 
         where tbl_products.product_id = s.product_id 
       )
) 
-      (SELECT sum(quantity) 
          from sales as f 
         where tbl_products.product_id = f.product_id 
       )
)
```

but give me wrong output

**Is There a way I can update the column quantity for each product in the products table using a single query?**

Comment: ? Your first query would produce a syntax error. Likewise, your second query and your UPDATE; all produce syntax errors. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My first and second query are just giving an overview of how am getting the totals and they don't give any errors